# What's the difference between "delay" and "latency" in computer networks?

Tags: networking, computer-science

Sometimes when I'm reading a paper in the field of computer networks, I found that in the evaluation part of the papers, some evaluation indexes are "delay", but some are "latency". So What's the difference between "delay" and "latency" in computer networks?

Answer (score 1):

Latency is a measure of delay. In a network, latency is usually measured as a delay in a round trip–the time taken to get back and forth to a destination because the TCP / IP network sends a limited amount of data to its destination and then waits for the confirmation to be returned before further sending. [refrence][1](https://www.sas.co.uk/blog/what-is-network-latency-how-do-you-use-a-latency-calculator-to-calculate-throughput)